# Need help getting swift app to display reverse string on label correctly

Tags: swift, string, text, label, reverse

I'm a novice and i'm practicing by making an app that takes a string through a text box and on a button click displays the string, reversed, on a label. I'm pretty sure i have the part about reversing the string correct, but i'm not exactly sure where i'm going wrong because i'm getting two errors.

one is "Argument to @IBAction method cannot have non-object type 'String'

the other "Cannot assign value to type 'ReversedCollection to type 'String?'

I'm not sure what i'm doing wrong since i haven't grasped the concept of taking a function by button action and having what is returned display on a label 100%. Help would be greatly appreciated.

Heres the code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
@IBOutlet var input1 : UITextField!
@IBOutlet var label : UILabel!

@IBAction func reverse(_ input1: String){
let output = input1.characters.reversed()
label.text = String(output)
}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
}
```

Comment: try wrapping `String` around `output`, `String(output)`

Comment: @iamjhu still getting a Argument to '@IBAction method cannot have non-object type 'String' to it.'

Comment: what happens if you remove `String` from `input1: String` in the func definition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume your `reverse` func is hooked up to the button's touch-up-inside, and you created it by Ctrl-dragging from the button to code. This would have created the correct parameter, which you then changed to have type String. When the button is touched, the parameter it sends is the button itself (eg. as `sender: AnyObject`).

You should change the function back to what it was originally, and then change your code to:

```
let output = input1.text.characters.reversed()
```